# Pandas - Matching rows in 2 dataframes by non-unique key without reusing rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 Pandas dataframes which I want to join:

**DF_Transactions**

| H1 | H_date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2-Jan-20 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 |
| C | 3-Jan-20 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 |

**DF_Events**

| H1 | H_date | H_class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |

Using pd.merge(DF_transactions, DF_Events, on=['H1'], how='left') I have obtained too many duplicates

**DF_Wrong_Results**

| H1 | H_date | H_class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| C | 3-Jan-20 |  |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |

I cannot use drop_duplicates on the dataframe as it would remove the last 2 entries in the left dataframe. What is the simplest way to get the correct dataframe below?

**DF_Correct_Results**

| H1 | H_date | H_class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |
| C | 3-Jan-20 |  |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_1 |
| A | 2-Jan-20 | class_2 |

Please see the sample code below:

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# list of strings
lst1 = ['A','A','C','A','A']
lst2 = ['2-Jan-20','2-Jan-20', '3-Jan-20','2-Jan-20','2-Jan-20']

lst3 = ['A', 'A']
lst4 = ['2-Jan-20', '2-Jan-20']
lst5 = ['Class_1','Class_2']

# Calling DataFrame constructor on list
# with indices and columns specified
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2)), columns=['H1', 'H_date'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst3, lst4, lst5)), columns=['H1', 'H_date', 'Class'])

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['H1', 'H_date'], how='left')

print(df2)
```

Comment: Try `pd.merge_asof`, with the by parameter

Comment: I can't reproduce `DF_Wrong_Results` using  `pd.merge(DF_transactions, DF_Events, on=['H1'], how='left')`. Instead, I get something similar to `DF_Correct_Results` but with two columns for `H_date`, one from transaction data and another from event data.

Comment: Apologies the data set was not simplified correctly, the 'B' should be changed to 'A'. Sample code is attached.

Answer (score 0):

according to pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
your code should be as such

```
DF_transactions.merge(DF_Events, on=['H1'], how='left')
```

It should be (left dataframe).merge((right dataframe),) syntax.
Try again and see if it works.

Comment: The dataset for DF_transactions yesterday had a typo and I have since updated. Unfortunately the answer you provided has the duplicates and I have no way of removing the correct duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```py
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(['H1', 'H_date']), 
              df2, 
              on='H_date', 
              by='H1')

  H1     H_date  H_class
0  A 2020-01-02  class_1
1  A 2020-01-02  class_1
2  B 2020-01-02  class_2
3  B 2020-01-02  class_2
4  C 2020-01-03      NaN
```